# C - Appending strings at beginning and end of while loop

Tags: c, string, printf, concatenation, modulo

I'm trying to construct a string - for every 80 chars in the loop, to add 7 tabs to the beginning of the line, and a new line at the end.

It should print out 7 tabs, then 80 chars, then 1 new line and so on.

However, something strange is happening. It's printing a new line straight after the first 2 chars and then everything is skewed from then on.

I'm also not sure why I need % 40 rather than % 80 - is it because there are 2 bytes?

I think generally im getting confused by 2 bytes.

```
void do_file(FILE *in, FILE *out, OPTIONS *options)
{
    char ch;
    int loop = 0;
    int sz1,sz2,sz3;

    int seeker = offsetof(struct myStruct, contents.datas);

    //find total length of file
    fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_END);
    sz1 = ftell(in);

    //find length from beggining to struct beginning and minus that from total length
    fseek(in, seeker, SEEK_SET);
    sz2 = sz1 - ftell(in);

    int tabs = (sz2 / 80) * 8;// Total size / size of chunk * 8 - 7 tabs and 1 new line char
    sz3 = ((sz2 + 1 + tabs) * 2); //Total size + nuls + tabs * 2 for 2 bytes

    char buffer[sz3];

    char *p = buffer;

    buffer[0] = '\0';

    while (loop < sz2)
    {
        if(loop % 40 == 0){
            //Add 7 tabs to the beginning of each new line
            p += sprintf(p, "%s", "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
        }

        fread(&ch, 1, 1, in);
        //print hex char
        p += sprintf(p, "%02X", (ch & 0x00FF));

        if(loop % 40 == 0){
            //Add a new line every 80 chars
            p += sprintf(p, "%s", "\n");
        }
        strcat(buffer, p);
        loop++;
    }
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: The `strcat` man page says `The strings may not overlap`. Also are you sure that `buffer` is large enough?

Comment: _It should print out 7 tabs, then 80 chars, then 1 new line and so on._ - did you mean **hexadecimal representation** of 80 chars (that is 160 chars) or hexadecimal representation of 40 chars, that takes 80 chars in output ?

Comment: I guess 40 hex chars 80 chars in total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, something strange is happening. It's printing a new line straight after the first 2 chars and then everything is skewed from then on.

It's because of the initial value of `loop`, try with `int loop = 1;`

> I'm also not sure why I need % 40 rather than % 80 - is it because there are 2 bytes?
>
> I think generally im getting confused by 2 bytes.

The point is, for each character you read in input file, you write two characters in `buffer`, because you decided to print characters as two bytes (`%02X`).

Now what is your need:

- insert LF and tabs each 80 characters of the **input** file? (Is that your expecting?)
- insert LF and tabs each 80 characters of the **output**? (That is what you coded)